# Best practices for creating and managing list of daily goals

Tags: ios, date, timezone

What are best practices for creating and managing list of daily goals.
I would like to have an entity for each day (called dailyGoal). Whenever user opens an app, the app first looks if an entity for this date was already created and creates a new one if it does not exist.
I am having some problems with time zones. 
User creates dailyGoal entity in New York and travels to San Francisco in the same day (and vice-versa). I cannot just use midnight date to fetch existing entity because midnight dates are different in this case. I tried using time intervals but this is also not a good solution.

Thanks!

Matic

Answer (score 0):

The entity can be based exclusively on year/month/day. Whenever a user opens the application, you extract year/month/day from the local date/time. If there exists an entity for year/month/day you use that, otherwise you make a new entity for the year/month/day.

In practice, this means that the entity will persist for 27 hours on a day trip from NYC to San Francisco, and for 21 hours on a day trip from San Francisco to NYC. But that aligns with the user's perception––the day seems to go by slower traveling from the east to the west of the USA because you gain 3 hours, and the day goes by faster when you travel from the west to the west to the east of the USA because you lose 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can easily solve the problem of timezones by normalizing daily goal dates to noon instead of midnight. That way, UTC date is always correct regardless of time zones.